# Regex not working in bash

Tags: regex, bash

My regex:

```
 (<property\sname=\"uri\"\s[value=\"htttp:\/\/]+(\d+\.)+\d+)+
```

Text sample:

```
 <bean id="journeyWSClient" parent="abstractClient" class=" lib.JourneyWSClient">
        <property name="uri" value="http://192.24.342.432:20010/some/path/1_0_0"/>
        <!-- Fortuna -->        
        <!-- property name="uri" value="http://164.7.19.11:20010/some/path/1_0_0"/ -->
```

It works on http://regexr.com/, however when I put the regex in bash script, it doesn't work. Are there some characters I need to escape? Ideas?

Bonus cookie for extracting the IP with only one regex.

Comment: Certainly you need to replace `\d` with `[0-9]`/`[[:digit:]]` and `\s` with `[[:space:]]`. And replace `[value=\"htttp:\/\/]+` with `value=\"htttp:\/\/`, and replace `(\d+\.)+\d+` with `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)` to get the IP into a capture group 2.

Comment: Also `htttp` with `http`, use do not use `[]` for value...

Comment: Check [`regex='<property[[:space:]]name="uri"[[:space:]]value="http://([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)'`](https://ideone.com/8nBWno)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1030675

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thanks, this worked.

Comment: @choroba I'm not using regex as HTML parser, just to compare IPs from a XML file to one in ANT build .properties.

Comment: It's still much easier to use an XML-aware tool.

Comment: @choroba Any commandline tools? I'd like to keep everything in one script, this is only a small part of much larger validation (that doesn't include XML).

Comment: `xmllint` should be enough for simpler tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `\d` with `[0-9]` and `\s` with `[[:space:]]`, and adjust the IP matching part as `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)` (or simplify it to `([0-9.]+)`) so as to be able to get its value with `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`:

```
text='<property name="uri" value="http://192.49.200.142:20010/some/path/1_0_0"/>'
regex='<property[[:space:]]name="uri"[[:space:]]value="http://([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)'
if [[ $text =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8nBWno)

Comment: why replacing `\d` with `[0-9]`?

Comment: @JobaDiniz POSIX regex flavor does not support `\d`.

Comment: I'm trying to convert this _semver_ regex to shell script: `^((0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))(?:-((?:0|[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$` and it works on regex101 but not on shell :(

Comment: @JobaDiniz Sure, POSIX regex flavor does not support non-capturing groups, replace all `(?:` with just `(`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you..

```
value="http:\/\/(([0-9].?)+):
```

This worked for me if you have IP only with http pattern

```
grep http TEXT_SAMPLE_FILE |sed -E    's;.*value="http://(([0-9].?)+):.*;\1;g'
```